# How do I tell a DataProvider to update?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dataprovider

I'm using an array to populate a DataProvider, which I'm using to populate a list component. Like this:

```
var myDataProvider = new DataProvider(this.myArray);
this['list'].dataProvider = myDataProvider;
```

When changes are made to the array, I want to tell the DataProvider to update so that those changes will be reflected in the list component. It would be nice if there was a way to tell the DataProvider to listen for changes in the array and update itself, but I would settle for a way to manually update it.

I can replace the DataProvider with a new DataProvider, but then the list loses its selection. I suppose I could go through the DataProvider and compare and modify every entry to make it match the array, but this seems way too cumbersome. Is there any way to tell a DataProvider to update to match an array?

Edit: I'm looking for a way to do this in Flash, not Flex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are not bindable in AS 3; they don't dispatch/trigger data binding events themselves.

If you are working with Flex, you can wrap your array in an `ArrayCollection` which *is* bindable, and manipulate the `ArrayCollection` instead of the `Array`, everything should automatically work as you hope.

So, in practice:

```
var myAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(myArray);
var myDP = new DataProvider(myAC);

myAC[0] = 'changing the array!'; // will be reflected in the dataProvider
```

Better yet, if you're passing that `DataProvider` instance to a Flex component, you can usually (almost always) just pass the `ArrayCollection` instead. But, you haven't shown enough context for me to be sure on this.

Here's a few useful links:

- [Binding to functions, Objects, and Array](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_4.html)s
- [ArrayCollection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html)

**Edit:** My fault, I did indeed assume you were using Flex for the above.

In plain old AS3, the principal is the same. The `Array` does not dispatch events, but the [`DataProvider`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/) does. If you can make your changes *to the dataProvider itself* then you're good to go.

The AS3 `DataProvider` class offers a bunch of methods for data manipulation, like `addItem`, `removeItem`, `replaceItem`, `replaceItemAt`, just for example.

So, it basically comes down to what kind of changes you need to make to the source array. More often than not, you'll be able to do them via the `DataProvider`.

Comment: Thanks but I'm pretty sure that ArrayCollection is a Flex class. Is there a way to get this functionality in Flash?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I considered this, but the source array is created in a different class, which uses it just as an array. It seems a little klugey to rewrite it to use a DataProvider. Is there no way to just tell the DataProvider to reconfigure itself to match the changed array?

Comment: Since objects are passed by reference, the DataProvider and the class that creates the Array can each use the array as needed, without knowing about each other. There should be no need to modify the other class.

Comment: @Tyler: But... The DataProvider cannot be / is not aware of changes to the Array. Sure, it has a reference to it, but it doesn't know it changed, because an Array does not dispatch change events.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent the last 4 hours trying to figure out what the connection between a dataprovider and the original array is.  I've found that using the GetItemAt method on the datagrid also updates the array that the datagrid's dataprovider is made from automatically updates when I use the GetItemAt method.

```
import fl.events.ListEvent;
import fl.data.DataProvider;

var arr = new Array();
arr.push ({Name:"Mike",Height:"6'4"});
arr.push ({Name:"Jackie",Height:"5'9"});
arr.push ({Name:"Mike",Height:"0'10"});

dg.addColumn("Name");
dg.addColumn("Height");
dg.dataProvider = new DataProvider(arr);
dg.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK,updatename);

function updatename(e):void {
e.target.getItemAt(e.rowIndex)["Name"] = name_txt.text;
trace (arr[e.rowIndex]["Name"]);
}
```

What annoys me is that I use the removeItemAt method, it removes the row from the datagrid, but doesn't update the array.  At the start of this project, I had no idea that getItemAt would update the array and so that's why I spent 4 hours trying to figure out how my code was subtracting twice.

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines, if you update the array, it will automatically update the datagrid (at least with Flash CS4).

```
import fl.events.ListEvent;
import fl.data.DataProvider;

var arr = new Array();
arr.push ({Name:"Mike",Height:"6'4"});
arr.push ({Name:"Jackie",Height:"5'9"});
arr.push ({Name:"Mike",Height:"0'10"});

dg.addColumn("Name");
dg.addColumn("Height");
dg.dataProvider = new DataProvider(arr);
dg.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK,updatename);


function updatename(e):void {
    arr[e.rowIndex]["Name"] = "none";
}
```

However, you still can't remove a row in the array using arr.splice and have it automatically update the datagrid.  For deletions(splice) and additions (push), you have to update the array and the datagrid separetly.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data and then asign the dataprovider again

```
var myDataProvider = new DataProvider(this.myArray);
this['list'].dataProvider = myDataProvider;

myDataProvider.getItemAt(0)["Name"] = "Some change";
this['list'].dataProvider = myDataProvider;
```